# Using Ply With iPython/Jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ply

I am working on a project that uses the ply parsing tool. I need to implement the project in iPython but as seen in this post
[Problems with PLY LEX and YACC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565547/problems-with-ply-lex-and-yacc), ply is causing issues with the tool. As such, I wanted to know if there is a fix or workaround for the issue that will allow me to use ply and the notebook tool at the same time.

Comment: From the question you linked to: "Ply insists that the grammar be a module, which means it must be in a file." An IPython notebook is not a file. You can try saving the grammar as a file somewhere on your system and importing it into a notebook, I suppose.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Just to be clear, a notebook is a file (`.ipynb`), but not a module.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a little bit late for a response, but I just faced the same problem and managed to find a workaround.

To build the lexer, PLY requires a variable named `__file__`. So, before calling `lex.lex()`, you have to set `__file__` to the name of your notebook file.

For example:

```
[...]
__file__ = "My_Notebook.ipynb"
lexer = lex.lex()
[...]
```

And if you are using a class (following this [example](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn17)):

```
class MyLexer(object):
    # [...]
    # lots and lots of token declarations
    # [...]

    # Build the lexer
    def build(self,**kwargs):
        self.lexer = lex.lex(module=self, **kwargs)

my_lexer = MyLexer()
__file__ = "My_Notebook.ipynb"
my_lexer.build()
```

Also you shouldn't define more than one lexer per notebook file, as pointed by the [PLY documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) at the end of section 4.15.

Now, to use `yacc` in IPython/Jupyter Notebook, you have to call it like this:

```
parser = yacc.yacc(write_tables=False)
```